# What I am supposed to return from a server-side method called by ajax?

Tags: ajax, jquery, spring-mvc

I have the following jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#resendActivationEmailLink").bind("click", function(event) {
        $.get($(this).attr("href"), function() {
            $("#emailNotActivated").html("<span>not yet activated. email sent!</span>");
        }, "html");
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Basically, when a user clicks a link the following server-side method is invoked:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/resendActivationEmail/{token}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody
    String resendActivationEmail(@PathVariable("token") String token) {
        preferencesService.resendActivationEmail(token);
        return "dummy";
}
```

and some business logic is executed on the server but **there is no real outcome from the server to be used on the client/browser side apart from an ajax success or an ajax failure**.

Now what **I am really not sure about is what my server-side method is supposed to return!**

Currently it just returns the string `dummy` but of course this is only temporary. Should I go for no return type (`void`) or `null` or something else??

*Note that I can change the **datatype** parameter of the jQuery get method.*

**EDIT:**

I have altered my server-side method as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/resendActivationEmail/{token}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody void resendActivationEmail(@PathVariable("token") String token) {
        preferencesService.resendActivationEmail(token);
    }
```

`@ResponseBody` is required because this is an ajax call.

Comment: It really doesn't matter, there doesn't need to be a return of any type.

Comment: The returned data is passed as an argument to the callback function. Since your callback function doesn't have any parameters, it ignores this.

Comment: It would be great for validation's sake if the function returned a boolean `true` or `false`. What does the preferencesService function return? If it returns a boolean just return whatever value that function returns. Then in your jQuery you can tell the user whether or not the email was really sent, or send it to a log somewhere.

Comment: @DaneHillard: preferenceService returns void

Comment: Thanks Jay and Barmar! I have edited my post according to your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in returning a dummy value in this case. If you are not doing anything with the return value, then you can just do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/resendActivationEmail/{token}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT) 
public void resendActivationEmail(@PathVariable String token) {
  preferencesService.resendActivationEmail(token);
}
```

There will be a `204` response code instead of a `200` but that should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are returning JSON from the server (from your server code: produces = "application/json").

Since you don't care about what gets returned, i.e. you are not handling the return value in your callback function, after $.get, then you can just return "{}", or if you want to handle the response you can go with something like:

```
{ "success": true }
// or
{ "error": "Error messages here" }
```